# Recursively PUT files to a remote server using FTP

Tags: recursion, ftp, data-transfer, put, ftp-client

I'm currently in a situation where I have very limited access to a server, but need to upload and download a significant amount of files contained within a single directory structure.  I don't have SSH access, so I can't use SCP - and rsync isn't an option either unfortunately.

I'm currently using ncftpput, which is great but seems to be quite slow (in spite of a fast connection).

Is there an alternative / better method I could look into?

*(Please accept my apologies if this has been covered, I did a quick search prior to posting but didn't find anything that specifically answered my question)*

Comment: for ncftp - are you using "put -R" command to do a recursive directory upload?

Comment: I am indeed - I think part of the problem is FTP is quite antiquated.. so there might not be an ideal solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using LFTP:
http://lftp.yar.ru/

or YAFC:
http://yafc.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: thanks very much for these .. I've just compiled YAFC, and it seems to be very good

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good connection, I would recommend mounting the ftp server via the GNOME or KDE file managers, or else using [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/). Then you can treat it like just another folder.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. There is no way that doing this would be faster than FTP, and it's a lot more risky, especially with high volumes of data, as it doesn't support resume on interrupt. And if he doesn't have access to SSH, how is he going to configure it for mounting?

Comment: No server configuration is required. The server is already configured for FTP. And the point isn't to make things faster, it's to make them easier. After mounting with CurlFtpFS, once could use standard unix utils like cp and rsync. I did say it works best with a good connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `ncftpput`. For non-interactive FTP, I've always used the Perl Net::FTP module -- http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html

This will be faster because you can login, then do all the transfers at once (it seems from a cursory glance that you execute `ncftpput` once for each file get/put).

Just remember to NEVER use ASCII mangling! This is the default, so use:

```
$ftp->binary
```

ASCII mangling needs to die in the same fire with MySQL automatic-timezone-interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

Since I always end up having a problem with this, I'll post my notes here:

One thing I always get to confuse is the syntax; so below there is a `bash` tester script which creates some temporary directories, then starts a temporary ftp server, and compares `rsync` (in plain local file mode, as it doesn't support ftp) with `lftp` and `ftpsync`.

The thing is - you can use `rsync /path/to/local /path/to/remote/`, and rsync will automatically figure out, that you want a `local` subdirectory created under `remote`; however, for `lftp` or `ftpsync` you **have** to specify the target directory manually, as in `... /path/to/local /path/to/remote/local` (if it doesn't exist it will be created).

You can find the `ftpserver-cli.py` in [How do I temporarily run an FTP server? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17084/how-do-i-temporarily-run-an-ftp-server); and `ftpsync` is here: [FTPsync](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ftpsync) (however, note it is buggy; see also [Search/grep ftp remote filenames - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117797/search-grep-ftp-remote-filenames));

Here is a shortened output of the `puttest.sh` script, showing the recursive put behavior in different cases:

```
$ bash puttest.sh 
Recreate directories; populate loctest, keep srvtest empty:
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt

*NOTE, rsync can automatically figure out parent dir:
+ rsync -a --exclude '*.git*' /tmp/loctest /tmp/srvtest/
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
└── loctest
    └── tempa1.txt
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt
cleanup:
+ rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/loctest

Start a temporary ftp server:
+ sudo bash -c 'python /path/to/pyftpdlib/ftpserver-cli.py --username=user --password=12345 --directory=/tmp/srvtest &'
+ sleep 1
Using: user: user pass: 12345 port: 21 dir: /tmp/srvtest
[I 14-03-02 23:24:01] >>> starting FTP server on 127.0.0.1:21, pid=21549 <<<
[I 14-03-02 23:24:01] poller: <class 'pyftpdlib.ioloop.Epoll'>
[I 14-03-02 23:24:01] masquerade (NAT) address: None
[I 14-03-02 23:24:01] passive ports: None
[I 14-03-02 23:24:01] use sendfile(2): False
test with lftp:

*NOTE, lftp syncs *contents* of local dir (rsync-like syntax doesn't create target dir):
+ lftp -e 'mirror -R -x ".*\.git.*" /tmp/loctest / ; exit' -u user,12345 127.0.0.1
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
└── tempa1.txt
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt
cleanup:
+ rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/tempa1.txt

*NOTE, specify lftp target dir explicitly (will be autocreated):
+ lftp -e 'mirror -R -x ".*\.git.*" /tmp/loctest /loctest ; exit' -u user,12345 127.0.0.1
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
└── loctest
    └── tempa1.txt
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt
cleanup:
+ sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/loctest

*NOTE, ftpsync syncs *contents* of local dir (rsync-like syntax doesn't create target dir); also info mode -i is buggy (it puts, although it shouldn't):

*NOTE, ftpsync --ignoremask is for older unused code; use --exclude instead (but it is buggy; need to change  in source)
+ /path/to/ftpsync/ftpsync -i -d '--exclude=.*\.git.*' /tmp/loctest ftp://user:12345@127.0.0.1/
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
└── tempa1.txt
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt
cleanup:
+ sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/tempa1.txt

*NOTE, specify ftpsync target dir explicitly (will be autocreated):
+ /path/to/ftpsync/ftpsync -i -d '--exclude=.*\.git.*' /tmp/loctest ftp://user:12345@127.0.0.1/loctest
show dirs:
+ tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest
/tmp/srvtest
└── loctest
    └── tempa1.txt
/tmp/loctest
├── .git
│   └── tempa2.txt
└── tempa1.txt
cleanup:
+ sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/loctest
+ sudo pkill -f ftpserver-cli.py
```

And, here is the `puttest.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

# change these to match your installations:
FTPSRVCLIPATH="/path/to/pyftpdlib"
FTPSYNCPATH="/path/to/ftpsync"

{ echo "Recreate directories; populate loctest, keep srvtest empty:"; } 2>/dev/null

sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

mkdir /tmp/srvtest

mkdir -p /tmp/loctest/.git
echo aaa > /tmp/loctest/tempa1.txt
echo aaa > /tmp/loctest/.git/tempa2.txt

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, rsync can automatically figure out parent dir:"; } 2>/dev/null

rsync -a --exclude '*.git*' /tmp/loctest /tmp/srvtest/

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo "cleanup:"; } 2>/dev/null
rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/*

{ echo -e "\nStart a temporary ftp server:"; } 2>/dev/null

# https://askubuntu.com/questions/17084/how-do-i-temporarily-run-an-ftp-server

sudo bash -c "python $FTPSRVCLIPATH/ftpserver-cli.py --username=user --password=12345 --directory=/tmp/srvtest &"
sleep 1

{ echo "test with lftp:"; } 2>/dev/null
# see http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/19/lftp-cheetsheet
# The -R switch means "reverse mirror" which means "put" [upload].
{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, lftp syncs *contents* of local dir (rsync-like syntax doesn't create target dir):"; } 2>/dev/null

lftp -e 'mirror -R -x ".*\.git.*" /tmp/loctest / ; exit' -u user,12345 127.0.0.1

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo "cleanup:"; } 2>/dev/null
rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/*

{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, specify lftp target dir explicitly (will be autocreated):"; } 2>/dev/null

lftp -e 'mirror -R -x ".*\.git.*" /tmp/loctest /loctest ; exit' -u user,12345 127.0.0.1

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo "cleanup:"; } 2>/dev/null
sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/*

{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, ftpsync syncs *contents* of local dir (rsync-like syntax doesn't create target dir); also info mode -i is buggy (it puts, although it shouldn't):"; } 2>/dev/null
{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, ftpsync --ignoremask is for older unused code; use --exclude instead (but it is buggy; need to change `  'exclude=s' => \$opt::exclude,` in source)"; } 2>/dev/null

$FTPSYNCPATH/ftpsync -i -d --exclude='.*\.git.*' /tmp/loctest ftp://user:12345@127.0.0.1/

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo "cleanup:"; } 2>/dev/null
sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/*

{ echo -e "\n*NOTE, specify ftpsync target dir explicitly (will be autocreated):"; } 2>/dev/null

$FTPSYNCPATH/ftpsync -i -d --exclude='.*\.git.*' /tmp/loctest ftp://user:12345@127.0.0.1/loctest

{ echo "show dirs:"; } 2>/dev/null
tree --noreport -a /tmp/srvtest /tmp/loctest

{ echo "cleanup:"; } 2>/dev/null
sudo rm -rf /tmp/srvtest/*


sudo pkill -f ftpserver-cli.py

{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

No mention of [ncftp](https://www.ncftp.com/)?

In Ubuntu, `sudo apt install ncftp`